# Installation and configuration of Jenkins on windows 7 with auto-install JDK

Tags: java, windows-7, jenkins, java-7

I'm going through [jenkins-the-definitive-guide](http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide).  I have installed Jenkins on Windows 7 64 bit using the windows installer.  I've configured a build and setup Jenkins to auto-install JDK 7u3 on the first build.  When the build kicks off I see this in the console logs:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\gameoflife-default
Installing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\JDK_7u3\jdk.exe 
[JDK_7u3] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\JDK_7u3\jdk.exe" /s /v /qn /L '\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\JDK_7u3\jdk.exe.install.log\"' REBOOT=ReallySuppress 'INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\JDK_7u3\"'
```

It never progresses beyond this.

I've tried:
- ensuring the exe is not blocked
- ensuring the service account has admin privileges
- tried installing other JDKs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If your main interest is to get a working build (rather than to become an expert in configuring Jenkins) then disable auto-installation and install JDK manually. In my experience JDK auto installation is nothing but trouble. Make sure to set JAVA_HOME correctly.

Comment: That exactly what I ended up doing, however it would be nice for the auto-installer to work.  I was just wondering if I was doing something silly.  Now I've found issues in the git plugin for windows... but that's another topic.

Answer (score 6):

There is an error in the JDK auto-installation for JDK7, it seems:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5408

If you try running that command on the command line, you get the `msiexec` dialog box, which implies that a parameter is incorrect.  Since I am also having this issue, I went and looked at what Jenkins actually passes.  It does (in our case):

```
c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\jdk.exe /s /v /qn /L \"c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\jdk.exe.install.log\" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=\"c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\"
```

The escaped quotes are a holdover from old-style `msiexec` installations, where everything after the `/v` had to be in single quotes because it was all getting passed through to something else.  The single quote escapes were removed, but the actual syntax isn't correct any more either (the installer has changed, as have the options).  The issue is the quote escaping being done in the `INSTALLDIR` variable.  If you remove that, it will sort-of-install (you may still have an msiexec process hanging).  Example:

```
c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\jdk.exe /s /L \"c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\jdk.exe.install.log\" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=\"c:\jenkins\tools\JDK\jdk-1.7.0_06\"
```

You might be able to go even further and use `/norestart` rather than setting the reboot property, depending on whether or not it's respected.

All these suggestions I'm making still don't get to the actual problem, which is 'how to auto-install JDK7 correctly'.  If you're having this problem, I don't know that you can without finishing the installation manually and then turning off auto-install in the main config. For me, cleaning the cache files didn't seem to help.